# How to decode PHP serialized Redis response with Golang

Tags: php, serialization, go, redis

I have a problem with my Redis db, it is encoded with PHP serialized protocol but I don't how I can decode this data using Golang, is there something like JSON Unmarshall/Marshall for this?

Comment: Use JSON if  you want to serialize/deserialize  between multi languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read such data in your Go program you will have to reimplement `unserialize` PHP function in Go. I doubt it is an easy task though.

A better solution would be to use a portable format to store data in Redis, such as JSON or Google Protobuf.

Comment: This is correct. The format also depends on the PHP version. For scalar PHP types, the decoding is quite trivial. However, for objects, you need information about their classes. See [this](https://3v4l.org/8DYb7) for example.

Comment: Another alternative is to store the data in a Redis hash if it primarily consists of k/v mappings.

Comment: I know.. i would love to use json, But all the redis db is encoded like that and it is very complicated to migrate all the service to json format.

Comment: I choose to migrate the redis db json format, thanks for help and have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

I found this https://github.com/wulijun/go-php-serialize i don't know if you already use it

Comment: And here is one more : https://github.com/yvasiyarov/php_session_decoder/tree/master/php_serialize

Comment: this one its pretty nice

Comment: But i can't convert the result in json

Answer (score 0):

Just reimplement php's  `serialize` and `unserialize` in golang

https://github.com/Trim21/go-phpserialize

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32208861)